# Foundation utils is not working in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use `Foundation.utils` in IE8 but I always get true on small only and false on the rest, for example:

```
Foundation.utils.is_small_only() = true all the time
Foundation.utils.is_small_up() = false
```

Of course the above can't happen because if it is small only, then it's for sure small up...

Any fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written my own solution to support utils in ie8.
I built it specific for my use (it could be done much better but why to make the effort? it's only for ie8..), still I believe you can use it, even with minor tweaks.

```
var win = $(window),
    bodyFontSize = parseInt(body.css('fontSize'));

function matchMediaQuery(mediaQuery)
{
    var winWidth = win.outerWidth(),
        winHeight = win.outerHeight(),
        mediaQuerySizes = mediaQuery.match(/\d+\.?\d*em/g);

    if (mediaQuerySizes == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        mediaQuery = mediaQuery.replace(/^(only screen)( and )?/,'').replace('min-width:',winWidth + '>=').replace('max-width:',winWidth + '<').replace('min-height:',winHeight + '>=').replace('max-height:',winHeight + '<').replace('orientation:landscape',winHeight + '>' + winWidth).replace(' and ',' && ').replace(' or ',' || ');
        for (var i = 0, len = mediaQuerySizes.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            mediaQuery = mediaQuery.replace(mediaQuerySizes[i],parseInt(mediaQuerySizes[i])*bodyFontSize);
        }
        return eval(mediaQuery);
    }
}

$.each(Foundation.media_queries, function(key, value)
{
    eval('Foundation.utils.is_' + ((key.indexOf('-') > -1) ? key.replace('-','_') : key + '_up')  + ' = function() { return matchMediaQuery("'+value+'"); }');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 5 [doesn't support IE 8](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html) at all but you can try [this](http://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/article/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8).

Quoted from [Foundation FAQ](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html):

> **Why doesn't Foundation support IE7 or IE8? Or: why we don't support a dying species.**
>
> This is probably the biggest question we get. Consider this: most of
>   today's popular browsers automatically upgrade themselves including
>   Chrome, Firefox and Explorer (starting with 9). IE 8 is the last IE
>   supported on Windows XP, which Microsoft will officially stop
>   supporting next year. That played a part in our decision.
>
> Besides that, since Foundation 4, our framework is built mobile-first,
>   meaning it relies on media queries to layer in more complex layouts
>   and components. Browsers or devices that don't support media queries
>   will be restricted to a simple, single-column layout. In some ways,
>   Foundation 4 better supports IE6-7 insomuch as it provides a mobile
>   but not entirely broken experience. If IE8 support is important for
>   your users / customers, you can use Foundation 3.2, which supports
>   IE8. It's not mobile first but it's good stuff.